# how to convert an image into byte array format in php

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, arrays, soap-client

I am concentrating on building a new project which will search for an image and display the result. For that I'm using a `.NET` web service using SOAP client..

But in calling the function `UploadFile()`,the first parameter is the byte array format of the image,but every time it shows null..

my code is as follows..

```
  $client = new SoapClient("http://www.myserviceurl.com?wsdl");
  $byte_array = file_get_contents('mypic.jpg');
  $image = base64_encode($byte_array);
  $result=$client->Upload($image, "mypic.jpg");
  print_r($result);
```

but `$result` prints like this..

```
stdClass Object ( [UploadFileResult] => Buffer cannot be null. Parameter name: buffer )
```

Please help me by saying that how to get the `bytearray` of an image uploaded..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

**Check this**

```
<?php
$filename = "mypic.jpg";//Image path
$file = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = fread($file, filesize($filename));
fclose($file);
?>
```

Happy Coding!!